# How to get access to Logger object in a downstream object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Consider the following project structure for a .NET Core Web project.

MyApp.UI project (MVC) calls MyApp.BusinessRules calls MyApp.ServiceLayer calls MyApp.DbAccess project calls whatever.

In the front-end project (MyApp.UI), I've defined the `logger`.  I would like to get access to this instance of the `logger` in MyApp.DbAccess project (or any downstream project) without passing it up via parameters from controller actions.  I also can't do dependency injection that deep in the structure.

So how does one get access to the logger?

Comment: The logger should be defined in a lower project than the UI, otherwise all your other layers have a direct or indirect dependency on the UI layer, which isn't ideal. You can create another library, say `MyApp.Common`, and move the logger there.

Comment: What is "the `logger`"? Is it something of your own creation or are you using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` facade?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging logger factory basically.  Specifically with Serilog as the provider.

Comment: Why can't you use dependency injection for your db access logic? If you inject an `ILogger<T>` into the constructor of the db service (even if it is a singleton), then the logger will take care of logging scopes - ASP.NET Core will set up a logging scope per request.

Comment: @MartinUllrich can you provide a sample.  I am not fully grokking what you are saying.  The UI project doesn't have a reference to the DbAccess.  Only MyApp.ServiceLayer has a reference to it.

Comment: @Sam That's what I ended up doing.  Works well so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logger shouldn't be defined in the UI layer. It is a cross-cutting concern hence you should define it in an external library and reference that in all the projects you need logging.

If you only want to log exceptions, you could define a global exception handler, let the exceptions bubble up to the UI layer and log them there. Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

In the case you really want to pass your Logger all the way down, you could use `Action` as parameter in methods and pass a lambda with the method call you want invoked downstream.

```
    public class Logger
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void Log(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
        }
    }

    public class Business
    {
        public void DoWork(int id, Action<string> logAction)
        {
            if (id < 0)
            {
                logAction("The string is less than zero");
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling code

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
Business business = new Business();

business.DoWork(-1, (message) => logger.Log(message));
```

Comment: The logger is defined in Startup.cs and is tied to the WebHost.  It's not just for handling exceptions - it's also for tracing.

Comment: @AngryHacker Just updated my answer - you can define a lambda and pass it to your downstream methods: `Action<string> loggingAction = (message) => logger.Log(message); `

Comment: And what is the parameter list of `DoWork`?  Is it (int, Func)?

Comment: In my example this is the signature `void DoWork(int id, Action<string> logAction)` - it has an int and the lambda for logging